# How can I load my YAML file into a case class?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, case-class, snakeyaml

I have a Scala application that needs to read in a Yaml file and load it into a Scala case class. I'm using snakeyaml to do the job, but it seems that the load function can't use my case class's constructor. The following is an example of what I'm doing:

Yaml File:

```
name: "Jon"
age: 50
gender: "male"
```

Case Class:

```
final case class Person(
    name: String, 
    age: Int,
    gender: String
)
```

Code to extract and load YAML:

```
val text: String = scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).mkString
val yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass))
yaml.load(text).asInstanceOf[T]
```

I get the following error:

```
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.ConstructorException: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:case_classes.Person; exception=java.lang.InstantiationException: NoSuchMethodException:case_classes.Person.<init>()
```

What can I do, to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the error is because Snakeyaml attempts to call the no-args constructor and then set all properties using setters.

That will never work with a Scala `case class`, beacuse they neither have a no-args constructor nor setters. [**Source**](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-yaml-parser-parsing-examples-snakeyaml-objects).

For a workaround you can use [*circe-yaml*](https://github.com/circe/circe-yaml).

Comment: This solution worked for me. I used the circe parser to convert the YAML to a Json object. From there, I converted the Json to a String, so that I could use the Json4s reflection methods to map over the values to the case classes.

Comment: @NeedAnswersFast I'm glad that it worked for you. But I think you're doing a long trip... Circe provides a way for turning Jsons into case classes. That avoids you using another library and also the overhead of turning the Json into a String to parse it again to create the case class.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can provide `Circe` with the proper `Decoder` to convert the YAML over to my case classes. I will probably do that in the future, but since my app uses `Json4s` reflection for many case classes already, that will involve a great deal of refactoring.